# SELECT returns NULL if run from application

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005

I have an INSERT trigger on a view created with VIEW_METADATA.
There's the following snippet:

```
    if @has_folder is null set @has_folder=(select REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(COLUMN_DEFAULT, '(', ''), ')', ''), '''', '') from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where TABLE_NAME = 'people' and COLUMN_NAME = 'has_folder')
```

The whole point of this subquery is to set `@has_folder` to default value for a column if it is NULL. And to avoid editing trigger text if default changes. As the default value is stored in DB surrounded by double parentheses (`'((0))'`), I remove them.

It does work when I run an INSERT from SQL Server Management Studio, but it does not work when the same query is run from application (`@has_folder` stays NULL). The query is the same, I've checked with SQL Profiler.

If I set the statement to

```
    if @has_folder is null set @has_folder=0
```

it works, but then I'll have to change it manually if I decide to change the default value for that column in database.

In general,

```
select COLUMN_DEFAULT from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where TABLE_NAME = 'people' and COLUMN_NAME = 'has_folder'
```

returns correct value if run from SSMS, but NULL if run from application.

The same behavior is shown by

```
select definition from sys.columns 
join sys.tables on sys.columns.object_id = sys.tables.object_id
join sys.default_constraints on sys.default_constraints.object_id = default_object_id
where sys.columns.name = 'has_folder'
and sys.tables.name = 'people'
```

What is going on and how can it be fixed?

Comment: are you sure the quotes aren't messing up?

Comment: @WhatsThePoint what do you mean?

Comment: the question implied to me that you have the query pasted in your application, if that's the case the quotes in all the replaces could be messing up

Comment: @WhatsThePoint no, I didn't paste the query in my application. The cited query is contained inside DB trigger that is fired after INSERT into view.

Comment: it might be worth temporarily modifying the trigger just to log if its been called

Comment: @WhatsThePoint done that, the trigger is fired.

Answer (score 0):

try this approach

```
SELECT
    @has_folder = COALESCE(@has_folder,
                       (
                          SELECT 
                             REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(COLUMN_DEFAULT, '(', ''), ')', ''), '''', '')
                             FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
                                WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'people'
                                    AND COLUMN_NAME = 'has_folder'
                       ),
                       0
                    )
```

Comment: I removed the last argument to COALESCE (`, 0`) as I don't want to set default values explicitly and the `,*` part as it threw the error. Then ran the query. Doesn't work either.

Comment: you will get a value as NULL when there is no Default assigned for the column, that's why I added a 0 to the end.

Comment: Ah, I see. In my case, there is a default assigned, though. It isn't returned by the query for some reason.

Comment: can you Tell me what is the value stored in the filed COLUMN_DEFAULT ?

Comment: Sure thing. `((0))`.

Comment: If this is the value then normally it should work. But since you don't have a filter for the database and schema in your query, make sure that there are no multiple schemas on your database that have the same table and column but the default value is not set. If the selection returns multiple records it is possible that the first value will be taken and by default it will be null. So add a filter condition in the where clause for schema also order it by default value desc

Answer (score 0):

FYI, I had this same issue, and it was simply a matter of not having the correct permission with the account the application was running under.  Having just read/write permission wasn't sufficient.  Adding Owner permission did resolve the issue.  I'm sure there's some level between those two that may work, but wanted to post this so that others know to look in that direction if they have this problem.

Comment: Your answer is ok since you wanted to give an helpful comment... but in general if you added the line required to give the GRANT it would count as a perfect answer candidate to be the accepted one